# Insert row below a specific text (text occurrence times) vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel, insert, rows

This code searches all "-" in column A and when it finds that character in a cell, adds a new row below:

```
    Sub insertRow()
      Dim c As Range
      For Each c In Range("A:A")
        If c.Value Like "*-*" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
      Next c        
    End Sub
```

I want to insert a row below every "-". If there are three "-" in a cell, I want to add three rows below that row and put in the text after every "-". How can I do that?

e.g.:
        column A:
        str1-str2-str3-str4
        str5
        str6-str7
        str8-str9-str10
        str11-

and the result like this:
        column A:
        str1
        str2
        str3
        str4
        str5
        str6
        str7
        str8
        str9
        str10
        str11

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work - it relies on the array base 0 default indexing. If execution time is a concern, there may be ways to optimize though

```
Sub t_exe566965()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim a As Variant
    For Each r In Range("A:A")
        If r.Value Like "*-*" Then
            Debug.Print True
            a = Split(r.Value, "-")
            r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(a)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                r.Offset(i, 0).Value = a(i)
            Next i
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I have another doubt. I want to copy another columns (B,C,D) below, in the cells I created before. I created a b range (for example Range("B:B")) and I tried to put in the value from the column B(I mean to complete blank cells with above cells value)..like this:          For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)                       b.Offset(i, 0).Value = b(i)                Next i.                Why doesn't work? why doesn't copy the value into the cells? help me, pls!

Comment: I mean: For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a) b.Offset(i, 0).Value = a(i) Next i